# how to enable TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 on nginx Debian squeeze?

Tags: nginx, debian-squeeze, tls, security

For security I have to setup a nginx server with TLSv1.1 or TLS v1.2.
By default, nginx configuresTLSv1.

Reading the documentation I see that nginx has to set the following directive:

`ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;`

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

But when I run the command:

`# /etc/init.d/nginx configtest`

Following message appears:

`Testing nginx configuration: [warn]: invalid value "TLSv1.1" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf: 175
configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Is documentation lies?

platform is Debian Squeeze and nginx version is 0.7.67

thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to archive.org ( http://web.archive.org/web/20120116033748/http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html ) TLSv1.2 support was added between january and february 2012. Nginx 0.7.67 is from 2010.

You might want to use the backport of nginx 1.2 ( http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=nginx ) and you almost certainly want to look into upgrading the OS :P

Comment: Thanks for responding

Apart from updating nginx, would need to update the openssl package or version already supports 0.9.8o TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2?

Comment: @Gon At this point squeeze is so ancient you're almost certainly better off rebuilding the server on an up-to-date distribution, which Debian almost never is.

Answer (score 2):

openssl @ squeeze is: `OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010`, but you'll need 1.0.1x, so you'll have download openssl-sources and tell nginx @ compile-time which version to use:

```
./configure ... --with-http_ssl_module  \
                --with-openssl=/path/to/openssl_source/ ...
```

i wouldnt recommend to update the system's openssl-packages from backports et al.